# PassportJS middleware being called multiple times

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

It seems whenever I call Passport's `ensureAuthenticated` middleware, it causes the `passport.deserializeUser` function to be called upwards 6-7 additional times. I'm not sure if it's my app's structure via Express, Sequelize, or the way Passport is being imported. For this reason, I'm going to lay out a few files in hopes of finding where its gone astray.

Here is how I have everything structured

```
application/
  auth/
  models/
  node-modules/
  public/
  routes/
  views/
  app.js
```

My assumption is it's either because the middleware is not a singleton, and/or it's because my routing is set-up oddly. **Note**: I followed [this](http://redotheweb.com/2013/02/20/sequelize-the-javascript-orm-in-practice.html) guide on setting up a singleton sequelize approach.

**./app.js**

```
// .. imports

app.set('models', require('./models')); // singleton ORM (my assumption)
// .. session stuff
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(require('./auth'));
// .. etc

app.use('/', require('./routes')); // routing style possible issue?

// .. create server
```

**./auth/index.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    var express   = require('express')
      , passport  = require('passport')
      , Local     = require('passport-local').Strategy
      , app       = express();


    passport.use(new Local(
        function(username, password, done) {
            app.get('models').User.find({
                where: {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                }
            }).done(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid login' });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        app.get('models').User.find(id).done(function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });


    return app;
}();
```

**./auth/middleware.js**

```
exports.check = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
};

exports.is = function(role) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.usertypes[req.user.type] === role) next();
        else res.redirect('back');
    }
};
```

**./routes/index.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    var express  = require('express')
      , app      = express();


    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        if (!req.user) res.redirect('/login');
        else res.redirect('/' + req.usertypes[req.user.type]);
    });

    app.use('/admin',    require('./admin'));
    app.use('/another1', require('./another1')); // yadda
    app.use('/another2', require('./another2')); // yadda
    app.use('/login',    require('./login'));

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });


    return app;
}();
```

and *Finally*, **./routes/admin.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    var express = require('express')
      , auth    = require('../auth/middleware')
      , admin   = express();


    // auth.check seems to be what's firing the multiple queries:
    // Executing: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=1 LIMIT 1;
    // 6 times from the looks of it.

    admin.get('/', auth.check, auth.is('admin'), function (req, res) {
        res.render('admin', {
            username: 'req.user.username'
        });
    });

    admin.get('/users.json', auth.check, auth.is('admin'), function (req, res) {
        res.contentType('application/json');
        admin.get('models').User.findAll().done(function (err, users) {
            if (users.length === 0) {
                // handle
            } else {
                res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
            }
        });
    });

    admin.post('/adduser', auth.check, auth.is('admin'), function (req, res) {
        var post = req.body;
        admin.get('models').User.create(post).done(function (err, user) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(JSON.stringify({success: true, users: user}));
            } else {
                res.send(JSON.stringify({success: false, message: err}));
            }
        });
    });


    return admin;
}();
```

I know it's a bit of code, but I have a feeling it's something very very simple. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: what editor/IDE are you using? I can highly recommend using Jetbrains Webstorm. You can answer your question quickly then by just adding a few breakpoints and checking the callstack.

Comment: Or, alternatively, call `console.trace()` from `deserializeUser`.

Comment: A log / trace from `deserializeUser` in `./auth/index.js` repeats with the SQL executions - that seems to be whats getting called numerous times. Also, just vim/zsh.

Comment: Make sure that your public folder is not being called through express but rather something in front of it (apache, nginx, whatever). Since each CSS/JS/img/etc. call will also trigger the middleware (happened to me).

Comment: @user766987 I just had that problem. The reason all your static assets are running through your middleware is because you are either not defining what are static assets or you're defining it too late. I had to tell it to use `/assets` as the base for the public files, and then you have to make sure it comes before your other `app.use` definitions. `app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: Gavin's comment is the answer in my case. This ordering around declaring static assets is quite a subtle thing to be aware of.

Comment: @Gavin Yup, that solved the issue for me as well. I strongly encourage you to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you are using your passportJS session middleware earlier than your static files. Because of that your all static file calls (like `<img src="...">`) passing thru session middleware and calling `deserializeUser()`.

**Solution**

Use your session middleware *after* `app.use(express.static(...))` in your **app.js** file.

Check jaredhandson's this GitHub issue answer for more details : https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/14#issuecomment-4863459

Answer (score 0):

I just had that problem. The reason all your static assets are running through your middleware is because you are either not defining what are static assets or you're defining it too late. I had to tell it to use `/assets` as the base for the public files, and then you have to make sure it comes before your other app.use definitions.

`app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`